# How would I save and close a .txt file from a batch program? Is it possible?

Tags: batch-file

I am attempting to make a rolling document that holds sensitive information, so I can't use something like google docs.  I am doing this because I have some time, and I am attempting to teach myself how to use batch.  I would like to save a close a document using a batch file.  I cannot find anything on it, and I am unsure how to do it.

I have attempted multiple small scripts, and nothing seems to give me what I am looking for.

```
@echo ^s >"C:\Users\josh\Documents\CallNotes2.txt"
```

Was hoping it saved all text in document, but it doesn't save anything

Comment: What do you mean by "close"? The code you've posted will write `s` into the specified file.

Comment: "it doesn't save anything" isn't quite right. It overwrites your file with the string `^s `. `cmd` has no method to talk to a GUI-Application. What you want isn't possible with batch (alone). You need (the help of) another language, like `VBS`, which has a [sendkeys](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) command.

Comment: Hey, I suppose it is an odd question.  The code above is as far as I could figure it out.  I was going to use vbs, but someone told me there isn't much support for it, and I wasn't sure.  I would like to be able to save and close the document with a script of some kind.  I looked into vbs, and maybe I will do some more searching.  Can you edit vbs in notepad++?

Comment: The script itself is pure text (like batch), so the answer would be a yes.

Comment: If I can find a resolution with vbs then I shall do it, and hopefully I can upload something here to help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey everyone who is looking at this.  I was able to sort this out.  I posted my answer in the comments above, but I figured this would be a way better use of your time ;)

So, for anyone wondering what this does or how it does it, here you go.

You have to create an object and that will be the wndShell that can now utilize functions of VBS. This is an odd program, but it worked well enough. SendKeys function is a great tool, but it does not always work, so you'll see that I have CTRL+S(`^s`) function and this will save the document and then ALT+F4(`%{F4}`) plus {ENTER}.  CTRL+S is to save and then ALT+F4 for exiting, but say that doesn't work because send keys is picky then there is a secondary method for closing because if the ctrl gets skipped and it jumps straight to closing then you have the secondary enter to hit save on the document.

I hope this helps, and please hit me up with any questions.  I tried to write to explain it to someone who has never dealt with it because that is how I started out with this and I want you to have a good jump start on this.

```
Set wndShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wndShell.AppActivate "CallNotes - Notepad"
WScript.sleep(500)
wndShell.SendKeys "^s"
WScript.sleep(500)
wndShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
WScript.sleep(500)
wndShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: I also wrote this in notepad and saved it as a .vbs file.  There is nothing else that really needs to happen unless you're going to mess with actual Visual Basic.  Good luck to you!